# SIGSEGV error on SPOJ

Tags: c, windows

I would like to solve problem PRIME1 on SPOJ. When I run Code Blocks and input test examples, I get correct answer. But when I submit my code to SPOj, I get SIGSEGV error. Here is the explanation of this error on SPOJ:
 SIGSEGV (signal 11) - the most common error for non-interpreted languages: a "segmentation fault" of the program. This may be caused e.g. by an out-of-scope array index causing a buffer overflow, an incorrectly initialized pointer, etc.
But I can't find this type of problem in my code. Could anyone help me, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int prim(int n)
{
    int s, i;
    if (n == 1 || n == 2)
        return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0)             
        return 0;
    s = (int)sqrt(n);           
    for (i=3; i<=s; i+=2)       
        if (n % i == 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

void print(int a,int b)
{
    int *p,i,k;
    int g;
    g=(b/2);
    p = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int)*(b-a+1));
    for(i=0;i<(b-a+1);i++) p[i]=a+i;
    for(i=0;i<=g;i++)
    {
        if(p[i] && prim(p[i]))
        {
            for(k=i*2+a;k<b-a;k+=i+a)
                p[k]=0;
        }
        if(!prim(p[i]))
        {
            p[i]=0;
            for(k=i*2+a;k<=b-a;k+=i+a)
                p[k]=0;
        }


    }
    for(i=0;i<(b-a+1);i++) if(p[i]!=0) printf("%d ",p[i]);
    free(p);
}

int main(void)
{
    int t,i,m,n;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
        print(m,n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that in the `print` function `g < b-a+1`? Otherwise your loop will go out of bounds.

Comment: If I put something different, I will get wrong answer, I thnik

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Werror -g main.c && gdb ./a.out` then `run`. It will show you exactly what line is causing the segfault.

Comment: I get: No such file or directory. Help?

Comment: I can't find what menas ./a.out ? is this .o file?

Comment: After run, I get: No executable specified, use `target exec'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that g maybe greater than or equal to (b-a+1), depending on the test case. Since `g = b/2` then for the array index `i` to not go out of bounds, `b/2 < b-a+1` which implies that `b/2 > a-1`. That is not necessary. Since `a` can be say 6 and `b` can be like 7 according to the problem constraints.

Also according to the constraints, your code might well give TLE. Your algorithm is currently in the worst case `O((n-m)*sqrt(n))`, which I think is not enough to get AC in this question.

Read about Sieve of Eratosthenes and try to use it to solve this.